# Default Featured Image versus Custom Featured Image, which one is better for the SEO purposes?

Tags: seo, wordpress, google-image-search

I have a WordPress website. The 99% of mine content is texts, so I'm not uploading any images or videos to the post. I know that having the "featured image" on a post is crucial for SEO purposes(search engines definitely will rank post and website higher if you have it).

I'm thinking of default featured image solution, so anytime when I will not upload the image manually - the default image(dummy image) will be applied to the post as "featured post's image". So the image will stay the same on 99% posts that I have, but the image attributes will be related to the post's title.

Is it really that bad, Or if I will upload the custom image on every new post it will be much much better in case of SEO?

Comment: 'I know that having the "featured image" on a post is crucial for SEO ' -- Where did you hear that?   I don't think it is true.   Search engines don't rank pages based on images.  At best it could help with user experience once users get to your page.  Maybe you mean that it is important for social media engagement?   Facebook does show the featured image when somebody shares your URL.

Comment: I also have never heard that featured images directly affect ranking. They could indirectly affect it, as Stephen mentioned, through social network engagement or on-page user engagement.

Comment: So you said search engine rankings not affected from the fact: does page contain the feature image in it or not? I didn't know that. But what if the user finding my website thru google images search, then I got more traffic, that way it's good for SEO. More traffic => good.

Comment: Google image search is driven by image quality (best is high resolution photographs), image uniqueness, and words surrounding the picture.    Google image search visitors rarely visit the underlying site, they often find the images they are looking for directly in the search results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stephen and Maximillian mentioned, search engine algorithms don't take into account whether a post or a page has an image on it or not. Now, yes, someone may discover your site through image search or share the image on social media. Also, a relevant image with good alt text and caption may raise the relevance of the page. But having or not having an image on a post is by itself not crucial for search engines to rank you.

Also, keeping in mind that search engines still ultimately look at relevance and popularity when ranking content for search queries, the actual website traffic is not a factor. It is only a factor when users come to that website via a relevant query. But you can have a junk website with loads of random (mostly bot) traffic that won't actually rank for anything, for example.

To answer your question, everything in your posts and pages should be relevant to the user. That includes images and their metadata. So you're better off tailoring images to your pages.

Now, there's nothing wrong with having a default image. For example, if someone shares your post on social media, it's better if an image (such as a company logo, or a photo of the website's subject) is present, since users do still click more on content where an image is present. However, using the same image with different alt tags or captions will be awful for users, and this manipulative behavior may even get your content devalued, if this is abused 99% of the time.

I would advise you to use relevant images and metadata whenever possible, and if you do have a default featured image, pick the best metadata as it relates to your website's overall purpose and stick with it.

Comment: You're welcome @TryastsyaTvoijMatery, good luck!